# Nhibernate Query with multiple one to many mappings

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm a beginner in NHibernate. I have to write a complex query on say an "Employee" to populate all the associations for Employee based on the where clause. What I'm looking for is similar to this - when you do a Employee.FindById(10) should fill up OwnedDepartment, SubscribedGroups etc.

The Employee model I need to populate is really heavy (many associations with other objects) 
but I need to populate only few associations. How do I achieve it using a query over? or any other approaches?

---

### Updated

I was reading about eager loading just now, has it something to do with the loading ? In my map I have not mentioned any loading techniques, so by default all of my employee's child element are getting loaded already. There is a bunch of queries getting triggered underneath.

Answer (score 0):

All the associations are lazy loaded by default. That means that the load is triggered when you access it - that's why so many queries are issued. If you want to eagerly load the data (which means either joining the tables or - rarely - doing additional select queries at once), you have to specify it in your mapping or query, depending how you fetch your data. The concept is generally called "eager fetching".

If you want to get a single `Employee` by ID, the standard way to do it is using `session.Get<Employee>(10)` - but that approach means that eager loads need to be specified in the mapping. For mapping by code it will be `c.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);` for collections or `c.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoProxy)` for many-to-one - see [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html) or [here](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) for details.

I prefer specifying that kind of things in the query - just where it is used, not globally for the whole entity, regardless who is fetching and what for. In LINQ provider you have `FetchMany(x => x.SubscribedGroups)` for collections and `Fetch(x => x.OwnedDepartment)` for many-to-one relations. You can find similiar options in QueryOver, if that's your choice.